# Does behavior-driven development use unit tests or integration ("assembly") tests?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, integration-testing, bdd, acceptance-testing

Should we classify BDD tests as "unit tests" or "integration tests" ("assembly tests" or "string tests")? Confused because technically BDD tests are run with *unit tools, though the tests might (and in most cases) cover several components as they would possibly be used to test use cases end-to-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BDD doesn't have just one kind of test. It uses both acceptance tests and unit tests.

It starts with acceptance tests. The purpose of acceptance tests is to define and verify application features *at a high level*. Acceptance tests are usually written with a BDD tool like JBehave or Cucumber, not with a unit-testing tool. You could write acceptance tests with a unit-testing tool, but that doesn't work as well as using a real BDD tool, because unit-testing tools mix specification and implementation in the same file, making it harder to focus on the behavior. Technically, acceptance tests are integration tests, because they run against the entire application stack.

Once acceptance tests are implemented, BDD moves on to testing that defines and verifies the *details* of the desired application behavior and ensures technical correctness.

- Additional integration tests might be written using the same tool as acceptance tests or might be written with a unit-testing tool but without isolating application layers. Even if they're written using the same tool as acceptance tests, they're just integration tests, because they're motivated by requirement details and engineering concerns, not by high-level requirements.
- BDD also uses regular unit tests to test requirement details and technical concerns.

A typical BDD test suite includes a full suite of acceptance tests, a limited number of integration tests (other than acceptance tests), and a large number of unit tests. Application layers close to the user (e.g. controllers) are often tested mostly or entirely in the acceptance tests, while lower layers (e.g. models) need more unit tests.

Comment: And since BDD tests often use Selenium also for testing UI journeys I guess they can also be useful as Regression tests. But question remains on whether BDD are Unit Tests or Integration Tests.

Comment: I agree Dave, reason I said xUnit is that (and I might be wrong) under the hoods Cucumber (or suchlike BDD  tools) might depend on xUnit (like JUnit) and you can run them with JUnit. Also, I guess Integration tests are another name for Assembly tests.

Comment: No, generally BDD tools (which are more or less acceptance-testing tools) are not built on top of unit-testing tools. But the important thing is not how the tools are implemented, but a) that BDD tools put the focus on behavior and not test implementation, and b) the role of each type of tool in different stages of development. I rewrote my answer; see if it's clear to you now.

Comment: Your answers have been helpful Dave, sadly what confuses me still is the classification of these tests. While they are written as acceptance tests around the acceptance criteria, I think that BDD are Assembly tests, because the user journeys or flows that we are testing involve (perhaps not necessarily) multiple components.

Comment: Yes, all acceptance tests (that's the usual term, not assembly) are integration tests. The point is that in BDD you write acceptance tests to specify the systems behavior, not because you're thinking about parts of the system. (In fact, you write the first test before the system exists and has parts.) After you've implemented all of your acceptance tests you might write more integration tests to improve integration coverage.